# Как подключить заголовки другого проекта из одного solution?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Пересмотрел уже все инструкции. К Решению с проектом, который собираюсь тестировать добавил тестовый проект с самими тестами. Уже и Source Directory указал  и ссылку указал на основной проект. А к классам обратиться так и не могу. Подскажите чего-нибудь.

IDE - VS 2015

Comment: Укажите среду разрабоки

Comment: Нужно собрать google test, потом, в своём проекте подключить собранные библиотеки. Что из этого у Вас не получается?

Comment: Так и сделал, в тестовый проект подключил gtest.lib. Начинаю писать тест, а обратиться к хидерам тестируемого проекта не поулчается. Уточняю: тестовый и тестируемый проект - разные проекты. Тестовый - в который подключил gtest.lib.

Comment: Т.е. в тестовом проекте видны заголовки google test, не видны заголовки проекта, который Вы хотите тестировать?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: Впредь, пожалуйста, задавайте вопросы по проблеме, которая Вас действительно беспокоит. Из Вашего вопроса вытекало, что у Вас проблемы с gtest, тогда как на деле это совершенно не так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно пойти в настройки проекта с тестами и в `VC++ Directories`, в поле `Include Directories` добавить директорию с заголовками, которые Вам нужны. Это будет выглядеть как-то так: `../ProjectToTest/Headers` — лучше задавать относительный путь, иначе всё сломается, если перенести в другое место.

Но нужно понимать, что заголовки это не единственная проблема; если проект, что Вы хотите тестировать имеет `cpp` файлы, тогда он должен быть библиотекой, которую Вы подключите к проекту тестов. В противном случае, подключив заголовки Вы получите ошибку компоновщика(linker).

И ссылка на MSDN, по которой можно узнать, как добавлять ссылку на соседний проект, чтобы автоматически `lib` использовался проектом текущим: [Adding references in Visual C++ projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47w1hdab.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Прошу прощения и благодарю. А можно собрать библиотеку из уже готового проекта, если я при создании не указывал, что это будет dll?

Comment: @Сергей, в настройках проекта, в `General/Project Defaults` можно сменить `Configuration type`

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.